# Laser Scan rotates with the robot in RVIZ

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, create-autonomy, 2dlidar, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently working on developing a ROS application for autonomous navigation using AMCl. I am first trying to get `move_base` to work before continuing with AMCL. I came across an issue that shows the LaserScan rotating in a similar fashion to the robot when I use `teleop_twist_keyboard` to manually rotate the robot. I am using the `rplidar_ros` package to run the lidar and the `create_autonomy` package for controlling the robot. I have tried searching for an issue similar to mine and could not find one.

**Hardware**:

- Robot: iRobot Create 2
- Lidar: RPLidar A1M8
- Computer: Jetson NX with Ubuntu 18 running ROS Melodic

**Launch File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  
  <arg name="use_robot" default="true" />
  <arg name="use_gazebo" default="false" />
  <arg name="gui" default="false"/>
  

  <include if="$(arg use_gazebo)" file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find example_bot_sim)/worlds/maze.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Spawn Robot 
       This must be the same robot type as the robot application
  -->
  <include if="$(arg use_gazebo)" file="$(find example_bot_sim)/launch/spawn_bot.launch">
      <!-- Override arg parameters here e.g,
          <arg name="x_pos" default="10.0"/>
          <arg name="y_pos" default="5.0"/>
     -->
  </include>


 
  <include if="$(arg use_robot)" file="$(find ca_driver)/launch/create_2.launch" />
  
  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  base_link laser 100" />


  <include if="$(arg use_robot)" file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/rplidar.launch" />
  
  <include file="$(find example_bot_sim)/launch/gmapping.launch"/>

  <include file="$(find example_bot_sim)/launch/move_base.launch"/>


  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>

  
</launch>
```

**Initial robot pose:**

[image]

**Robot pose after moving:**

[image]

`rosrun tf view_frames` **output:**

[image]

P.S. This is my first time posting on ROS Answers, so suggestions on how to better provide more detail for future problems will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358396/laser-scan-rotates-with-the-robot-in-rviz/) by [anonymous57168](https://answers.ros.org/users/57168/anonymous57168/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-07-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daenerys](https://answers.ros.org/users/75237/daenerys/) on 2021-06-12**:
Hi! I was wondering if you eventually fixed this problem, since I am facing the exact same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. check ur wheel separation distance , is it mentioned properly in ur URDF
2. try to set update_min_a = 0.2 or 0.1 (of amcl parameter this has worked for me  ) [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)

---

Originally posted by [Nitesh_j](https://answers.ros.org/users/54485/nitesh_j/) with karma: 65 on 2020-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0